# error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos'

Tags: iphone, ios4

While I am trying to launch (EPT)iPhone application on my apple machine whose version is. But I am getting the error "error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos'", though I have selected version from project->edit active targets. Could any body please help me in this as I have struck in this for the last 4 days.I have XCode installed in my system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no SDK with the name or path “iphoneos4.0”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393002/there-is-no-sdk-with-the-name-or-path-iphoneos4-0)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found this answer:  [XCODE Base SDK Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4831367/5188)

This fixed the problem for me.

> As well as the Deployment Target, you need to set the Base SDK.
>
> Go to the Project menu, then Edit Project Settings. Select the Build
>   tab, and near the top, there is a Base SDK setting.
>
> Sometimes, you also need to clean all targets, and restart Xcode for
>   it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer to this here: [There is no SDK with the name or path "iphoneos4.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393002/there-is-no-sdk-with-the-name-or-path-iphoneos4-0/3393069#3393069)

The short version is, you've got a trivial misconfiguration in the MANY configuration parameters of your project. Not hard to fix, but it takes some digging to see WHERE to fix it.