# XCODE Base SDK Missing

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4

I have a application built on IOS 4.1 but recently I have upgraded my XCODE to 3.2.6 which supports IOS 4.3.

How can I run this application in this XCODE. All I am seeing is the "Base SDK Missing" message even though I am choosing the deployment target SDK as 4.1.

Please suggest.

Comment: Next time, please try searching. For example, search for "Base SDK Missing", you might be surprised by what turns up...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install xCode 3.2.3 w/ iPhone SDK 4, get "Base SDK missing", can't see other SDKs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385/install-xcode-3-2-3-w-iphone-sdk-4-get-base-sdk-missing-cant-see-other-sdks)

Comment: @Intentss ironically, this question is now  #1 hit on Google for "Base SDK Missing"

Comment: which really shows the quality of Apples documentation :-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As well as the Deployment Target, you need to set the Base SDK.

Go to the Project menu, then Edit Project Settings. Select the Build tab, and near the top, there is a Base SDK setting.

Sometimes, you also need to clean all targets, and restart Xcode for it to work properly.

Comment: Sometimes you need to select the target -> Get Info -> Base SDK
I had this issue today...

Answer (score 2):

It's also worth keeping the last released version of Xcode, and install the latest beta in a separate folder. (See [Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed) for details on how this is done.) Use the beta to test beta features only, and the final for all your other development work.