# Xcode 6 throws error when trying to open a project previously opened in Xcode 7 Beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode7-beta3

Developed an incomplete iPhone + Watch app in Xcode 7 Beta. Tested on iOS 9 + Watch 2.0. Now need to open this project in Xcode 6 to release.

Getting the following errors:

> Target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'macosx' platform
>
> Error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Users/a1/Desktop/GangstaDoc/watchos'

Anybody else have this issue? Any fixes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831187/xcode-base-sdk-missing/4831367#4831367

Comment: This is learning the hard way. The only solution I can think of is starting over and copying the code to a new project.

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode 6.4 stable release version maybe don't has support to 'Watch 2.0.'. Try open its current project in Xcode 7 beta and disable use of the Watch 2, so then open again on Xcode 6.

Other option is copying the source code manually and put in its new project on Xcode 6.

**Observation**:

- When the version of Xcode 7 will be released for public, then the feature of 'Watch 2.0' will be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6 doesn't support building watchOS 2 apps, so you won't be able to build with Xcode 6. It also doesn't support building iOS 9 apps.

You will only be able to build this project with Xcode 7.