# Compiling Xcode project from zipped open-source GitHub download

Tags: xcode, git, macos, cocoa, github

Possibly basic question but I'm not sure where to begin for an answer. I am very much a newbie to Xcode, Cocoa, Swift and Objective-C.

I'm interested in developing an open-source Markdown editor for the Mac that will build from existing open-source code. I have gone to GitHub to download the source code for two existing projects, [MacDown](https://github.com/MacDownApp/macdown) and [WriteDown!](https://github.com/youknowone/writedown) For both projects I download the project .zip file (and am happy that the button to do so is [now easily available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751227/how-to-download-source-in-zip-format-from-github/34174216#34174216)), and extract the .zip file's contents on my hard drive. In each project there is an .xcodeproj file which I open up in Xcode... and I see tons of errors, mostly because of things that are missing, so I cannot build and run them.

With WriteDown I see "missing base SDK" (and get a corresponding error when I try to run it), and many other files missing (frameworks, products, and "pods"). With MacDown I get a lot of errors mentioning missing pod files.

If it were just the one project that gave me errors I would assume this was something specific to that project, but since they're *both* giving me errors it sure seems like I'm doing something wrong in general. Should I be downloading something other than the downloadable zip? Downloading extra frameworks? Taking an extra step in between?

I am using Xcode 6.1.1 on OS X 10.9.5, which MacDown seems to indicate it's compatible with.

Comment: Let's take MacDown as an example. There is a [section of the ReadMe](https://github.com/MacDownApp/macdown/blob/master/README.md) that starts: "After cloning the repository, run the following commands inside the repository root"... You didn't do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about not bothering to read the ReadMe.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:
1) If an .xcworkspace is available, you should open that in lieu of the .xcproj.  The workspace contains multiple projects that are important for the building of the application.

2)
Check out this answer for "Missing Base SDK" [XCODE Base SDK Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831187/xcode-base-sdk-missing)

3) Go to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs` and check to make sure you have the proper system SDKs available

4) It looks like those projects also require [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/), a OS X Dependency Manager.  You need to download the "pods" AKA 3rd party dependencies in order to build the application